# Click behind fragment when DialogFragment is shown

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I need to have access for click on my behind fragment ( such as click on a button ) when DialogFragment is shown.

But when I click outside of DialogFragment, this will dismiss.

Used code to show **DialogFragment**:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

MyDialogMapFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogMapFragment();
dialogFragment.show( fragmentManager, "" );
```

**MyDialogMapFragment** Class:

```
public class MyDialogMapFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_map_info, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogMap);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map_info);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        return dialog;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            mActivity = (Activity) context;
        }

    }

}
```

**dialog_map_info.xml** Layout:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="90dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_map_info">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_loader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Test" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Below image will describe what is my layout:
[image: Sample of my layout]

Comment: any solution for this one?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember @NarekHayrapetyan

Comment: did you get any solution

Comment: Did any one find solution for this  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to detect a click the while a dialog is being shown it would be easier to set an onClickListener to a view on your dialog.

When you the onClickListener is called then you can either perform a click on the button button.perfomClick() or even better call the function that the button onClickListener calls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I just told the button, for example. Actually, I have a Map and some markers on map. When user click on marker, I'll show DialogFragment to user. And I want to give another chance to user for click on any behind markers.